# Configure hudson/jenkins to run at 6:00PM and 1 AM every day

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I need to able to configure every 6PM and 1 AM in build periodically section, any examples could you pass on?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Each Job has a `Build Trigger` section where you can configure to `Build periodically`. The syntax is cron-like so you have to add `0 1,18 * * *` to build at 1AM and 6PM.

Comment: Would be nice if you could mark this answer as 'accepted' then (left side below the number, click on the check mark).

Comment: Thanks Got the answer for my question here.

Answer (score 11):

Another Alternative is like `H(0-0) 1-18 * * *`

Jenkins cron has following syntax

```
1 Parameter - Minutes in one hour (0-59)
2 Parameter - HOURS Hours in one day (0-23)
3 Parameter - DAYMONTH Day in a month (1-31)
4 Parameter - MONTH Month in a year (1-12)
5 Parameter - DAYWEEK Day of the week (0-7)
```

Comment: Could you please help me setting the job every alternate day? like every Monday, Wednesday and Friday .